# Add apple-touch-icon to my application (from image file) not working

Tags: html, apple-touch-icon, web-clips, web-ide, sap-cloud-platform

I am working with SAP Hana Cloud trial version (SAP WEB IDE). I tried to add Home Screen feature to my application.
My project structure is:

http://scn.sap.com/servlet/JiveServlet/showImage/621327/structure.png

In index.html file I added line like this:

`<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="images/apple-touch-icon-iphone.png"/>`

Then I deploy my application, and when I try to add Home Screen on my iPhone 5s device (iOS version: 8), my image is not added.

Interesting is that, when I use image from internet (link to the image), then all works great - image is added to home screen:

`<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="http://www.platinumpay.net/images/EP_employees.png">`

Can you please help, what could be wrong? Image path or something in deffinition?

BR, Kristaps

Comment: Hi, 

Maybe the problem is caused by SAP HANA CLOUD Security conditions? 

Any ideas?

BR, Kristaps

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you out? 
http://chrislowthian.co.uk/web-development/add-favicon-apple-touch-icons-website/